# How to efficiently sample edges from a graph in relation to its spanning tree

Tags: probability, graph-theory, algorithms

Consider a connected, unweighted, undirected graph $G$. Let $m$ be the number of edges and $n$ be the number of nodes.

Now consider the following random process. First sample a uniformly random spanning tree of $G$ and then pick an edge from this spanning tree uniformly at random. Our process returns the edge.

If I want to sample many edges from  $G$ from the probability distribution implied by this process, is there a more efficient  (in terms of computational complexity) method than sampling a new random spanning tree each time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the other answer is correct, it requires the computation of $|E| + 1$ many determinants.  There is a faster route when $|E|$ is large.  The first thing to note is Kirchoff's theorem which states that if $T$ is a uniform spanning tree then
$$P(e \in T) = \mathscr{R}(e_- \leftrightarrow e_+)$$
where $e = \{e_-, e_+\}$ and $\mathscr{R}(a \leftrightarrow b)$ is the effective resistance between $a$ and $b$ when each edge is given resistance $1$.  This implies that the probability an edge is sampled in your process is $$\mathscr{R}(e_- \leftrightarrow e_+)/(|V| - 1).$$

Thus we only need to compute the effective resistance.

If we let $L$ denote the graph Laplacian and $L^+$ to be its Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse, then

$$\mathscr{R}(a \leftrightarrow b) = (L^+)_{aa} + (L^+)_{bb} - 2 (L^+)_{ab}. $$

(See [this master's thesis](https://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/scripties/EllensMaster.pdf) for some nice discussion and references.)

Thus, the only computational overhead for computing the marginals is computing a single psuedoinverse.  Depending on how large $|E|$ is, this may be faster than computing $|E|$ many determinants.

EDIT: some discussion on complexity

The Pseudoinverse of an $n \times n$ matrix [can be done in](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/0804/0804.4809.pdf) $O(n^3)$ time.  So computing $L^+$ takes $O(|V|^3)$ time.  We have to compute this for $|E|$ many edges, so the above computes all marginals in $O(|E| |V|^3)$ time.  Conversely, a determinant can be done in, say, $O(n^{2.3})$ time.  So the other answer has complexity $O(|E|^2 |V|^{2.3}).$  Since $G$ is connected, $|E| \geq |V|-1$ and so this algorithm is always faster (asymptotically, at least).

Comment: This is great. I wonder if this is as fast as it gets.

Comment: A correction on the complexity: (i) the pseudoinverse can be calculated in matrix multiplication time (see e.g. [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/24060/complexity-of-finding-the-pseudoinverse-matrix)), which is $O(n^{2.373})$, (ii) you only have to calculate it once - after that you can just read off the eff.resistances in constant time. This gives a total time complexity equal to the matrix multiplication time, $O(n^{2.373})$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\tau(G)$ denote the number of spanning trees in $G$, and let $G \bullet vw$ denote edge contraction: it is the *multigraph* in which adjacent vertices $v$ and $w$ are replaced by a single vertex $x$, and all edges incident to either $v$ or $w$ are changed to be adjacent to $x$.

The spanning trees of $G$ containing edge $vw$ are in bijection with the spanning trees of $G \bullet vw$, and so the probability that your process will return $vw$ is $$\frac{\tau(G \bullet vw)}{\tau(G)} \cdot \frac1{|V(G)|-1}.$$
We can efficiently compute $\tau(H)$ for any multigraph graph $H$ using [Kirchhoff's matrix tree theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_theorem).

(Rather than dealing with $G\bullet vw$, we could also count the spanning trees containing $vw$ as $\tau(G) - \tau(G-vw)$, but that's slightly less efficient, because the determinants are one bigger.)

Answer (score 1):

Approximately sampling according to the effective resistances is done in the sparsification algorithm of Spielman and Srivastava. See Theorem 2 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0803.0929). The complexity has a one-off cost of $\tilde{O}(m)$, and then cost $\tilde{O}(1)$ per sample.